# Launch spring batch jobs from control-m

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-batch, control-m

I developed jobs in Spring Batch to replace a data loading process that was previously done using bash scripts.

My company's scheduler of choice is control-m. The old bash scripts were triggered from control-m on file arrival using a file watcher.

For reasons beyond my control, we still need to use control-m. Using Spring Boot or any other framework tied to a webserver is not a possibility.

The safe approach seems to be to package the spring batch application as a jar and trigger from control-m the job using "java -jar", but this doesn't seem the right way considering we have 20+ jobs.

I was wondering if it's possible to trigger the app once (like a deamon) and communicate with it using JMS or any other approach. In this way we wouldn't need to spawn multiple jvms (considering jobs might run simultaneously).

I'm open to different solutions. Feel free to teach me the best way to solve this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The safe approach seems to be to package the spring batch application as a jar and trigger from control-m the job using "java -jar", but this doesn't seem the right way considering we have 20+ jobs.

IMO, running jobs on demand is the way to go, because it is the most efficient way to use resources. Having a JVM running 24/7 and make it run a batch job once a while is a waste of resource as the JVM will be idle between run schedules. If your concern is the packaging side of things, you can package all jobs in a single jar and use the spring boot property `spring.batch.job.names` at launch time to specify which job to run.

> I was wondering if it's possible to trigger the app once (like a deamon) and communicate with it using JMS or any other approach. In this way we wouldn't need to spawn multiple jvms (considering jobs might run simultaneously).

I would recommend to expose a REST endpoint in your JVM and implement a controller that launches batch jobs on demand. You can find an example in the [Running Jobs from within a Web Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/job.html#runningJobsFromWebContainer) section. In this case, the job name and its parameters could passed in as request parameters.

Another way is to use a combination between Spring Batch and Spring Integration to launch jobs using JMS requests (`JobLaunchRequest`). This approach is explained in details with code examples in the [Launching Batch Jobs through Messages](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#launching-batch-jobs-through-messages).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the helpful answer from Mahmoud, Control-M isn't great with daemons. Sure, you *can* launch a daemon but anything running for a substantial length of time (i.e. into several weeks and beyond) is prone to error and you can often end up with daemons that are running that Control-M is no longer "aware" of (e.g. if the system has issues that cause the Control-M Agent to assume the daemon job has failed and then launches another one).

When I had no other methods available I used to add daemons as batch jobs in Control-M but there was an overhead in additional jobs that checked for multiple daemons, did the stop/starts and various housekeeping tasks. Best avoided if possible.